# Test URL for simulating upload and download multimedia (like steaming media, video, images)

Tags: android, url

I am having an app requirements like whatsapp application. The thing is that webservices are not ready and it will take time. Meanwhile I want the test URL which use JSON format to upload and download the videos and images.

I know the sample URL's for JSON simulation

1. http://www.jsontest.com/
2. http://www.mocky.io/

For HTTP GET and POST simulation

1. http://httpbin.org/

Like this I want it for images and video in the form of JSON upload/download.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a webservice to test download from android, just a server container like tomcat installed on your computer and place files you want to download on tomcats directory.

But you will need one for uploading to receive (even if it does nothing).

Comment: yes agreed but I need myself to setup for such things. Instead I am looking for readymade test webservice for this.

Answer (score -2):

You may use the following websites to download an image from

http://dummyimage.com/

Or this website

https://placehold.it/

You may also use the following website for video downloads

http://www.sample-videos.com/index.php#sample-mp4-video